# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "mora" y "demora"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, diferencias-entre-palabras, lenguaje-jurídico

Leyendo la noticia [*Indígenas del Cauca se declaran en "asamblea permanente" por constantes asesinatos*](https://www.elespectador.com/noticias/nacional/indigenas-del-cauca-se-declaran-en-asamblea-permanente-por-constantes-asesinatos-articulo-875611) aparecida en el diario El Espectador de Colombia, veo:

> "El Gobierno está en **mora** de aplicar una política coherente en el territorio, es decir el Gobierno debe disponer de una presencia integral de todas las agencias del Estado que garanticen una investigación y una atención de los derechos de la población", aseguró Cepeda.

Como veis, destaco la palabra *mora* pues su uso aquí me resulta curioso. Sigue lo indicado por el DLE en su primera acepción y es correctísimo:

> [**mora<sup>1</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Pliz3P1%7CPlk7QR8)
>   `Del lat. mora.`
>
> 1. f. Der. Dilación o tardanza en cumplir una obligación, por lo común la de pagar cantidad líquida y vencida.
>   2. f. Fon. y Métr. Unidad de medida de la cantidad silábica, equivalente a una sílaba breve.

Sin embargo, este uso perteneciente al Derecho me resulta curioso, máxime cuando en España hubiéramos usado *demora* en su primera acepción:

> [**demora**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=CAZPcqn)
>   `De demorar.`
>
> 1. f. Tardanza, dilación.
>   2. f. En la América colonial, temporada de ocho meses que debían trabajar los indios en las minas.
>   3. f. Der. Tardanza en el cumplimiento de una obligación desde que es exigible.
>   4. f. Mar. Dirección o rumbo en que se halla u observa un objeto, con relación a la de otro dado o conocido.

Por ello me pregunto: ¿cuál es la diferencia entre *mora* y *demora*? ¿Es la primera el término propio del Derecho que puede que con el tiempo sea equivalente a *demora* en el habla coloquial? ¿O acaso hay algún matiz en Colombia que se me escapa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*“Estar en mora”* es una expresión idiomática. La he escuchado muchas veces en Argentina. Si bien es más bien técnica, no es un término exótico. Sólo me parece un poco extraño el régimen preposicional, con *de*, porque generalmente escucho o leo *en* o *con*.

*Demora* es una palabra de uso mucho más general y no se usa en esta frase. Decimos que algo ha tenido o experimentado o sufrido una demora, o que algo está demorado, o que una demora tal es inaceptable.

*“Estar en mora”* implica una deuda o deber incumplido, mientras que *“estar demorado”* sólo implica tardanza.

*Mora* prácticamente sólo se usa para referirse a una tardanza legal o políticamente significativa, aunque también puede usarse de manera menos específica y más figurativa; decimos que alguien está en mora (de, con, en tal o cual cosa). Es raro verla fuera de esta estructura; si se usa sola, *mora* suena más legalista todavía. Al menos en Argentina tendemos a hablar de *morosidad* antes de que *mora* en este último sentido (y casi siempre se refiere a morosidad impositiva o crediticia, es decir, a la demora en pagar impuestos o deudas, o a no hacerlo por un tiempo indefinido). En el caso de una demora permitida o autorizada, hablamos de *moratoria*.

Answer (score 3):

*Mora* y *demora* tienen ambos raíz etimológica latina en *morari* que significa retrasar, demora tiene el agregado *de-* que da un sentido de inicio. La *mora* se utlizaba en el Derecho Romano para describir al retraso deliberado de un deudor en la prestación o cumplimiento de su obligación, y el Derecho Romano es un sistema que se sigue utilizando en muchos países con sus variantes. A través de éste siguió la palabra mora con el sentido que utilizaba el sistema jurídico en vez del uso que tenía en el idioma latín. Conforme fueron evolucionando los idiomas, mora paso en el español a demora para seguir significando retraso fuera del Derecho Romano. Por ello, ahora, mora se utiliza solo en el ámbito jurídico para el retraso deliberado en el cumplimiento de una obligación, y demora para todos los demás casos de retraso fuera de ese ámbito.